# What is the correct way to scale flink statefun remote function

Tags: kubernetes, apache-flink, flink-statefun

1. Figure out what is the correct way to scale up the remote function.
2. Figure out scaling relations between replicas of the remote function, Flink `parallelism.default` configuration, ingress topic partition counts together with message partition keys. What is the design intentions behind this topic.

As the docs suggest, one of the benefits of flink statefun remote functions is that the remote function can scale differently with the flink workers and task parallelism. To understand more about how these messages are sent to the remote function processes. I have tried following scenarios.

**Preparation**

1. Use https://github.com/apache/flink-statefun-playground/blob/main/deployments/k8s this for my experiment.
2. Modify the https://github.com/apache/flink-statefun-playground/blob/main/deployments/k8s/03-functions/functions.py to the following to check the logs how things are parallelized in practice

```py
...
functions = StatefulFunctions()


@functions.bind(typename="example/hello")
async def hello(context: Context, message: Message):
    arg = message.raw_value().decode('utf-8')
    hostname = os.getenv('HOSTNAME')
    for _ in range(10):
        print(f"{datetime.utcnow()} {hostname}: Hello from {context.address.id}: you wrote {arg}!", flush=True)
        time.sleep(1)
...
```

3. Play around the `parallelism.default` in the flink.conf, replicas count in the functions deployment configuration as well different partitioning configurations in the ingress topic: `names`

**Observations**

1. When sending messages with the same partition key, everything seems to be running sequentially. Meaning if I send 5 messages like "key1:message1", "key1:message2", "key1:message3", "key1:message4", ""key1:message5". I can see that only one of the pod is getting requests even I have more replicas (Configured 5 replicas) of the remote function in the deployment. Regardless how I configure the parallelism or increasing the ingress topic partition count, it always stays the same behavior.
2. When sending messages with 10 partition keys (The topic is configured with 5 partitions, and parallelism is configured to 5 and the replicas of the remote function is configured to 5). How the replicas remote function receiving the requests seems to be random. Sometime, 5 of them receiving requests at the same time so that 5 of them can run some task together. But some time only 2 of them are utilized and other 3 are just waiting there.
3. Seems parallelism determines the number of consumers in the same consumer group that subscribing to the ingress topic. I suspect if I have if configured more parallelism than the number of partitions in the ingress topic. the extra parallelism will just stay idle.

**My Expectations**

1. What I really expect how this SHOULD work is that 5 of the replica remote functions should always be fully utilized if there is still backlogs in the ingress topic.
2. When the ingress topic is configured with multiple partitions, each partitions should be batched separately and multiplex with other parallelism (or consumers) batches to utilize all of the processes in the remote functions.

Can some Flink expert help me understand the above behavior and design intentions more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things happening here...

1. Each partition in your topic is assigned to a sub-task. This is done round-robin, so if you have 5 topic partitions and 5 sub-tasks (your parallelism) then every sub-task is reading from a single different topic partition.
2. Records being read from the topic are keyed and distributed (what Flink calls partitioning). If you only have one unique key, then every record it sent to the same sub-task, and thus only one sub-task is getting any records. Any time you have low key cardinality relative to the number of sub-tasks you can get skewed distribution of data.

Usually in Statefun you'd scale up processing by having more parallel functions, versus scaling up the number of task managers that are running.

Comment: thanks a lot,  it makes a lot sense when you explain the topic are keyed and distributed (what Flink calls partitioning). I guess the remaining question is that how could we explain the behavior that the remote functions some time are not fully utilized even when there are still messages not processed in the ingress topic.

Comment: My guess is that statefun is not really doing any traffic routings/controls between the pods behind the service it send messages to. And if the request is sending to a busy function, it will come back and wait until it is ready. Does this mean we need to add some sort of service mesh or load balancer to balance traffic towards the functions seperately?

Comment: @joeyinso - the key to understanding Flink's behavior is that incoming records are keyed by user_id (in the playground example). This is how Flink routes records to sub-tasks, based on <murmer3 hash of user_id> % <number of sub tasks>. If each of your replicas is a Task Manager with one slot, then (depending on the values of your keys) you could get ALL keys going to one sub-task (and thus one replica), depending on what the hash-code mod 5 evaluates to.